# How can we avoid nested Collection.stream() calls?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

Let's say we have the following `Map`

```
Map<String, List<String>> peopleByCity = new TreeMap<>();
```

with the following content:

```
{ "London" : [ "Steve", "John"],
  "Paris"  : [ "Thierry" ],
  "Sofia"  : [ "Peter", "Konstantin", "Ivan"] }
```

With the tools of the Stream API, for each *pair* of type `[City ; Person]`, I would like to apply some operation, lets say printing:

```
 London : Steve
 London : John
 Paris  : Thierry
 Sofia  : Peter
 Sofia  : Konstantin
 Sofia  : Ivan
```

A possible (but not really neat) solution would be :

```
peopleByCity.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .forEach( entry -> {
                 String city = entry.getKey();
                 entry.getValue().
                      .stream()   <-- the nested Collection.stream() call
                      .forEach(
                         person -> System.out.println(city + ";" + person));
            });
```

How can we avoid the nested call to [`Collection.stream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#stream--) by creating some chain of calls to other Stream/Collector features?

Comment: A better question is, why do you think nested stream calls are something to be avoided?

Comment: @BrianGoetz, I was refactoring a code snippet with two nested for loops and I wondered is there a way to create a sequence of higher-order function calls, that work in a similar way to MongoDB's [$unwind](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way would be to "flatMap" the lists:

```
peopleByCity.entrySet().stream()
        .flatMap(e -> e.getValue().stream().map(p -> e.getKey() + ";" + p))
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Another way would be to use two `forEach`:

```
peopleByCity.forEach((city, people) -> 
        people.forEach(person -> System.out.println(city + ";" + person)));
```

But in the end I don't think there is a simple way around streaming the lists, unless you write a custom collector (but then the nested stream will be in the collector).

Comment: Works, but there's still a nested `.stream()` call in the `flatMap` `Function` body.

Comment: @kocko I can propose a second option

Comment: I like the second one better, although I am starting to think there's no way to escape calling higher-order functions in the lambdas (which is the general point of the question). You have my +1

Comment: As for the `flatMap()`, it's kind of wrong, since you're *flatMapping* `Map.Entry` objects, not `List`s :)

Comment: There’s nothing wrong with neither `flatMap` nor a nested `stream()` call. If you think about performance, using the `flatMap` approach and `collect`ing the `String`s into a single `StringBuffer` before printing out is the best choice for medium-sized streams.

Comment: @assylias, congratulations on 110k :)